# Checking and Verifying AUTH code after cancellation of purchase

Tags: domain, domain-registrar

Is there any online site to verify domain AUTH code once it retrieved. I've cancelled a purchase and waited for 60 days. Now while trying to transfer to new registrar it says wrong auth code. Since I don't have contract with previous registrar, I don't have idea that how to check the auth code once I got it. Is there any methods to do so?

Thinking of trying to transfer in the lock period it first checks the transfer state; Then only it verifies Auth code. So I think there is no possibility by this method in the first 60 days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AUTH code is just a random string and can consist of anything. It is given by one registrar (current domain hoster) to the domain owner. This AUTH code is then passed from the domain owner to another registrar (future domain hoster) for authenticating the domain action.

The new registrar then checks the AUTH code with the old registrar. If the code given equals the code presented then the domain action can take place. If not the domain action fails.

The only thing that is checked is the equality of the strings. So one registrar can hand out AUTH codes of "12345678" and others "abcdefg" and others "12-ab-34-XXX". There is no way to validate the code as there is no validating mechanism.

Comment: Is it possible that a AUTH code can vary depends on time? I requested one weeks before the cancellation of the package. So may be they changed it later?

Comment: @KingQuenJac Probably. As I said this only depends on your current domain hoster. He can change it every day, once per week, after each request or based on the phase of the moon.

Comment: Which means, I lost the control over my domain? Well - Is there any way to report it or fix it?

Comment: @KingQuenJac You can't lose the control. If you are the owner you have a current registrar. Call them! If you have no current registrar you are not the owner anymore. Your domain went back to the registry or got closed immediately. Look into the WHOIS to see the current status (owner, registrar, registry) and then act fast.

Comment: Yes. They changed the AUTH code due to auto generation request.I've got what I want. Thanks.